# Why ETH Transfer from Nethereum taking longer time then transfering from metamask wallet?

Tags: ether, metamask, nethereum

I am sorry for nubby question.

Today i made a ETH transfer of 0.00001 ETH 2 times. One programmatically with Netherium SDK and another directly through metamask wallet to another metamask wallet.
Here are the transaction hash.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb3fcd0c1466ad9dbb660b6c81812d82709acbbaaf08845995a6b2f42cea1f81d (With Netherium)
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc1c47dfedfbec85c4c97518ec0e3e3fbb8b78959de38cb9544c9fb9b9a5e4d70 (With Metamask Wallet Transfer)

However the first transaction is taking almost 2 hours and still is in pending while the second transfer was within 30secs. Although Both have similar gas values and transaction fee.

Is there any specific reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: U sent them at the same time !?

Comment: @MajdTL Yes i sent in almost same time. exactly at a difference of 10 mins to be precise. will this have an effect?.

Comment: The gas price and limit are usually the only elements which decide when a “pending & submitted” transaction will be confirmed (added to a block). the gas price change sometimes quickly so yes a 10 minute could be the reason. But I’m not 100% sure if that is only the reason